# Solving PDE analytically

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am solving a partial differential equation numerically (by [Explicit Scheme method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explicit_and_implicit_methods)), but also I have to check the *consistency* and *stability* of the method by comparing it with the analytical result. Could you help me find its analytical solution?

Consider the following PDE defined on $ \Omega \in R^n$ $( x \in [0, L] \quad \text{and} \quad t \in [0,t_{\text{max}}])$:
$$
(E) \left\{
\begin{array}{lcc}
\dfrac{\partial\theta }{\partial t}+rx\dfrac{\partial\theta }{\partial x}-\sigma^2\dfrac{x^2}{2}\dfrac{\partial ^2\theta }{\partial x^2}+r\theta=0, & 0<x<L, & 0<t<t_{\text{max}}\cr 
\theta(0,t)=0, &   & \forall t \in [0,t_{\text{max}}] \cr 
\dfrac{\partial \theta }{\partial x}(L,t)=0,&  & \forall t \in [0,t_{\text{max}}]
\end{array}
\right.
$$

$r$ and $\sigma^2$ are constants.

Can anyone help me to find its Analytical solution please?

Comment: Show something of what have you tried.

Comment: What is $r$ ? ...

Comment: You could change variables $x=e^{y}$ so that the equation becomes constant-coefficient, then separate variables $\theta(t,y)=e^{-rt}T(t)Y(y)$.

Comment: r and $\sigma^2$  are give constants

Comment: if I change variable $x=e^y$, how to perform the partial derivatives ?

Comment: By changing variable we get:
\begin{equation}\label{e}
\dfrac{\partial\theta }{\partial t}+\left( r+\dfrac{\sigma^2}{2} \right) \dfrac{\partial\theta }{\partial y}- \dfrac{\sigma^2}{2} \dfrac{\partial^2\theta }{\partial y^2}  +r\theta=0 
\end{equation}